# How to fix ordering in the generated table in JPA. Do we have some workaround without any framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Hibernate generates columns in alphabetical order. My requirement is to maintain proper order like below :

```
id
title
subtitle
created_on
```

and the table is getting created like this :

```
id
created_on
subtitle
title
```

Do we have some workaround without any framework?

Comment: Yeah, write the `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate guide

> Although the automatic schema generation is very useful for testing and prototyping purposes, in a production environment, it’s much more flexible to manage the schema using incremental migration scripts.

So create your schema yourself and manage it via an incremental migration tool like `flyway` or `liquibase`  is your best option.